# Common Lisp - how to say if a pathname points to a regular file or a directory?

Tags: common-lisp

Is it possible to 'stat' a file and find its file type - regular or directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several ways. `probe-file` followed by checking the returned true name to determine that it has a directory name but not a filename and type should do it. e.g. for a directory

```
(pathname-name (probe-file filespec))

-> NIL
```

Comment: While trying your solution I had to realize that this code will lead to an error in case there is no file or directory `filespec`. I'd suggest using an `and` for less error prone code: `(and (probe-file filespec) (not (pathname-name (probe-file filespec))))`

Comment: That won't work. It's not clear that `PROBE-FILE` works on directories. It's also not clear that `pathname-name` returns `NIL` for directories. Generally this functionality is not really provided by Common Lisp and most implementations have a function for that. Libraries provide portable names...

Answer (score 5):

Read the chapter about a [portable pathname library](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-portable-pathname-library.html) from Peter Seibel's [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) book. It's available for free. It has a function file-exists-p that will return a pathname when the file exists or nil if it doesn't. The returned pathname will be in directory form if it's a directory. He also gives another function for checking if the pathname is indeed in directory form.

BTW the whole book is really worth reading so check it out if you haven't already.

Comment: The CL-FAD library *is* Peter Seibel's chapter, packaged for general use.  The DIRECTORY-EXISTS-P function does exactly what you describe.

Answer (score 3):

[CL-FAD](http://weitz.de/cl-fad/) has a function [DIRECTORY-EXISTS-P](http://weitz.de/cl-fad/#directory-exists-p) which, when used in combination with [PATHNAME-AS-DIRECTORY](http://weitz.de/cl-fad/#pathname-as-directory) canonicalizes the pathname (prevents failure when handed a string like "/path/dir-without-trailing-slash") and achives what you're asking for.

(CL-FAD:DIRECTORY-PATHNAME-P (CL-FAD:PATHNAME-AS-DIRECTORY (PROBE-FILE "/path/missing-slash")))

Comment: It doesn't look like this will work with GCL. At least GCL is not listed under "Supported Lisp implementations"

Comment: I guess the good news is that, as GCL has not had a release in over half a decade, if you figure out how to do it there you probably won't have to worry about it changing on you any time soon!

Comment: I checked the source code of CL-FAD - the said function only works for Allegro and LispWorks.

Comment: hyper_w: The function only has *special cases* for Allegro and Lispworks.  The library claims to support 11 different compilers, and I bet it probably works for more than that.

Answer (score 0):

CLISP has a function [`EXT:PROBE-DIRECTORY`](http://clisp.cons.org/impnotes/dir-func.html#probe-dir), which tells you whether a file exists and is a directory.

Note that this function is specific to CLISP and not standard Common Lisp.

Comment: Am sorry but is GNU Common Lisp and GNU CLISP the same? I am using GNU Common Lisp (GCL 2.6.6 on Windows) but I could not find the said package "ext".

Comment: @hyper: No, GCL and CLISP are two different implementations of the Common Lisp language. Since you tagged this `clisp` I assumed you were using the latter.

Comment: Removed the clisp tag. Thanks!